# Apple developer - Update free app to subscription app

Tags: ios, subscription

I have a (ios)free app for a while now in appstore and I am considering to change it to subscription app in the next update. It will be a subscription with the first month free.
I would like to know, from the user point of view, how will he know that updating the app will change the type of payment from free to subscription ? Anyone has experience in the matter ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from a user standpoint it's quite common to update a well running app to subscription **But** usualy the users that already own your app are still free to use it. (it's like "you helped me ramp up my app" = "you get it lifetime free").

Otherwise you should make it clear in the release notes and maybe add a single screen for the first startup to make it more obviouse. But the user can't know it up front if for example auto updates are activated.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the advice. I shall put a screen informing the user regarding the changes.